# Eclipse indexer is not finding the functions using the android ndk

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm developing some stuff with the android NDK. I have some code that compiles good and works, but eclipse is just telling me all the time that some references are not found, like `std::function`. I added the following lines to the "Path and Symbols" of the project:

```
/Users/jpuig/Development/test/git/test_lib-protoype/test_lib/JuceLibraryCode
/Users/jpuig/Development/test/git/test_lib-protoype/test_lib/Source
/Users/jpuig/Development/test/git/test_lib-protoype/test_lib/juce_core

/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue/

/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/
/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/x86/include/
/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/backward/
/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/include
jni
/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/include
/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/include-fixed/

/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/include
/Users/jpuig/SDKs/android-ndk/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/include-fixed
```

And still doesn't work. Can anybody help me with that??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to fix it. I suffered from it for about two months, and after a while Eclipse started to block compilation because of these errors and debugging native code was really really buggy. Then I switched to Visual Studio using Nvidia Tegra Development Kit which comes with full native Android support.

Comment: That's too sad... I'm using a mac and I wouldn't like to move to windows just to debug android :( For now I'm using xCode and eclipse at the same time to debug/code android NDK

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not add a comment , I'll do it this way.
I hope it's not too late to help you.

Could you post your Application.mk file?
I have had the same problem and this is what fixed it.

If you have `#APP_STL := gnustl_static`in your .mk file , change it to `APP_STL                 := stlport_static`.